# Using react hooks inside render prop function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Taken from [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html):

> **Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.** Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function

Given this recommendation by the react team, would using a hook at the top of a render props function be inadvisable? Assuming it depends on the value returned by the function.

```
const MyComponent = () => (
    <RenderPropComponent>
        {value => {
            React.useEffect(() => {
                // Magic
            }, [value]);

            return <p>Hello</p>;
        }}
    </RenderPropComponent>
);
```

I don't feel like it breaks their requirement

> By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders

But should I be doing the following instead?

```
const MyComponent = ({ value }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // Magic
    }, [value]);

    return <p>Hello</p>;
};

const MyContainer = () => (
  <RenderPropComponent>
      {value => <MyComponent value={value} />}
  </RenderPropComponent>
);
```

Comment: I think both variants are not equivalent. Using JSX hides the actual `React.createElement('MyComponent', {value}, null)` part. I'm not saying this won't work, but option A looks odd to me.

Comment: @lipp yea I realise the difference, my question is if that difference matters

Comment: That said, I'd assume that option A invokes `useEffect` as a nested function of `RenderPropComponent` and thus should be avoided.

Comment: It's really an interesting question! I'd bet option A is discouraged :)

Comment: For instance, `RenderPropComponent` could call `children(value)` conditionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hooks keep track of current rendering element. And render prop function is not an element. So you will hook into calling element and not into your prop function. This render prop function will be treated as a custom hook. You will get unexpected behavior if `RenderPropComponent` calls render prop function conditionally.

Comment: Specifically (as of at least `React@16.12.0`, if not earlier), React will throw an error indicating the order of called hooks has changed, as the hook call stack extends through non-Component functions called within a Component (including render props).

Answer (score 0):

This does not break the rules of hooks - https://unsplash.com/blog/calling-react-hooks-conditionally-dynamically-using-render-props/#waitdoesntthisbreaktherulesofhooks